# Can I cut <img> tag from one paragraph and paste it to new line using regular expressions?

Tags: html, css, inline

Using regular expressions, I want to cut  tag from the paragraph given below and paste it to new line with

tag as shown below. please see below that paragraph.

```
 <div>
 <ul style="list-style-type:disc; margin:0pt; padding-left:0pt">
     <li style="font-family:serif; font-size:10pt; line-height:16pt; margin:3pt 0pt 3pt 9.6pt; padding-left:18.75pt; text-align:justify; text-indent:0pt">
     <img src="html1.015.png" width="490" height="215" alt="k-98" style="margin-left:13.75pt; margin-top:30pt; position:absolute; z-index:-65521" />
     <span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:10pt">As the gain of emitter follower is approximately equal to 1, there is no change in the signal swing. No voltage amplification is being provided to the input signal by this stage.</span>
     </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Also if possible i would like to edit as below,

like this.

Is there any solution using regex?

Comment: are you talking about doing this in Text Editor ?

Comment: [Mandatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)...

Comment: yes, I am using Ultraedit editor. after </div> on new line, I want <p class="center"><img src="html1.015.png" width="490" height="215" alt="k-98" style="margin-left:13.75pt; margin-top:30pt; position:absolute; z-index:-65521" /></p>

Comment: Also if possible i would like to edit as below,
<p class="center"><img src="html1.015.png" alt="k-98"/></p>  like this.